# Swift iOS15 async/await + basic authentication + http request slow(er)

Tags: ios, http, authentication, async-await

I am using the below code for basic http authentication. It is noticeably slower than when I wasn't using authentication (the below is called around 30 times)

Are there any speed optimization changes that could be made to the code ?

Thanks

```
struct PrixJSONService {
    
    let passwordString = "user:password"
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    
    enum PrixJSONServiceError: Error {
        case failed
        case failedToDecode
        case invalidStatusCode
    }
    
    func fetchPrix(for stationId:String) async throws -> [Prix] {
        
        let passwordData = passwordString.data(using:String.Encoding.utf8)!
        let base64EncodedCredential = passwordData.base64EncodedString()
        let authString = "Basic \(base64EncodedCredential)"
        let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration)
        
        configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = ["Authorization" : authString]
        
        let dataUrl = "https://xxxx.xx/~xx/xxxxxxxx/prix/\(stationId)/price.json"
        let url = URL(string: dataUrl)!
        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        
        urlRequest.setValue("Basic \(base64EncodedCredential)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        urlRequest.httpMethod = "GET"
        
        let (data, response) = try await session.data(for: urlRequest)
        
        guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse,

              response.statusCode == 200  else  {
                  throw PrixJSONServiceError.invalidStatusCode
              }
        
        let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode([Price].self, from: data)

        return decodedData
    }
    
}
```